# use a column as an input for to_tsquery

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I have a table `T1` with only one column having 2000 unique words. There is another table `T2` with a column of a word. I want to find the records in `T2` were their words matches with one of the words in `T1`.
So imagine `T1` looks as following:

```
word
------
regents
sky
tree
trees
avenue
```

and `T2` is like this:

```
tags    |  id|   usrid
--------+----+--------
shifs   |   1|      @1
trees   |   2|      @2
sky     |   3|      @3
regents |   4|      @4
regent  |   5|      @5
```

and I want to get results as follow:

```
tags    |  id|   usrid
--------+----+--------
trees   |   2|      @2
sky     |   3|      @3
regents |   5|      @5
```

I could use the below query to search the tags column from `T2` but I want to use the `word` column from `T1` as an input for `tsquery`.

```
SELECT *
FROM T2
WHERE to_tsvector(tags) @@ to_tsquery('regent');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a simple join between the tables:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM t1 JOIN t2
   ON t2.tags = t1.word;
```

No need for full text search!

Comment: thanks, it worked very well. just there is one problem. in T1 I have 'regents' and in T2 i have 'regent' and 'regents'. I want it only choose regents! but it does both of them.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use full text search; see my updated answer.

Comment: No, it's actually slower. Depending on the size of your tables, creating and index on one of them may help.